# How to use labview to control the voltage and current of Keithley 2400

Tags: usb, labview, gpib

I am currently studying how to control the voltage and the current of a source meter which is Keithley 2400 using Labview software. I am using GPIB controller to connect Keithley 2400 to my PC, however I don't have any experience using this labview software, can anyone suggest how to create this kind of program? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The **LabVIEW Instrument Driver Network** has support for the [Keithley 2400](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.download_page?p_id_guid=25B255F3AA83660EE0440003BA7CCD71), and the driver includes example VIs that show how to control this class of instrument.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few example LabView VIs available on the [Keithley 2400 download page](http://www.keithley.nl/products/dcac/dmm/broadpurpose/?path=2400/Downloads).

Answer (score 0):

While instrument drivers can be convenient, I find that its really useful to know how to control an instrument using instrument commands(SCPI for KE4200) and VISA VIs available on Labview as well. Sometimes instrument drivers default to certain settings you may not desire and may not even know about until you start digging. Of course its always possible to simply open them up and do just that.

Anyway the [image linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI6UF.png) shows how you could source and measure current using KE4200 and how to read out and parse the data returned.

If you're new to Labview, I also recommend watching the [VI-High video series](https://www.youtube.com/user/Sixclear/videos) on Youtube. All the best.